# c++ compiles in Ubuntu but not in centOS

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, centos

I have a bunch of code which compiles in Ubuntu using GCC 4.8.4.
When I transfer to centOS and compile it there the following errors occur:

```
[  0%] Building CXX object src/chrono/CMakeFiles/ChronoEngine.dir/core/ChClassRegister.cpp.o
In file included from /home/com/medyn/chrono/chrono_ver1/Chrono_source_Old/src/chrono/core/ChClassRegister.cpp:21:
/home/com/medyn/chrono/chrono_ver1/Chrono_source_Old/src/chrono/core/ChClassRegister.h: In destructor 'chrono::ChClassFactory::~ChClassFactory()':
/home/com/medyn/chrono/chrono_ver1/Chrono_source_Old/src/chrono/core/ChClassRegister.h:225: error: expected initializer before ':' token
/home/com/medyn/chrono/chrono_ver1/Chrono_source_Old/src/chrono/core/ChClassRegister.h:228: error: could not convert '((chrono::ChLog*)chrono::GetLog())->chrono::ChLog::<anonymous>.chrono::ChStreamOutAscii::operator<<(((const char*)"Delete ChClassFactory \012"))' to 'bool'
/home/com/medyn/chrono/chrono_ver1/Chrono_source_Old/src/chrono/core/ChClassRegister.h:229: error: expected primary-expression before '}' token
/home/com/medyn/chrono/chrono_ver1/Chrono_source_Old/src/chrono/core/ChClassRegister.h:229: error: expected ')' before '}' token
/home/com/medyn/chrono/chrono_ver1/Chrono_source_Old/src/chrono/core/ChClassRegister.h:229: error: expected primary-expression before '}' token
/home/com/medyn/chrono/chrono_ver1/Chrono_source_Old/src/chrono/core/ChClassRegister.h:229: error: expected ';' before '}' token
make[2]: *** [src/chrono/CMakeFiles/ChronoEngine.dir/core/ChClassRegister.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/chrono/CMakeFiles/ChronoEngine.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

These errors are for both GCC 4.4.7 and GCC 4.8.5.
The lines of code for which it gives the error are:

```
    ~ChClassFactory () {
    for(const auto & it : class_map ) {
       GetLog() << "   registered: " << it.first << "\n";
    }
    GetLog() << "Delete ChClassFactory \n";
    }
```

And the files included at the top of this script are:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>
#include "core/ChLog.h"
#include "core/ChRunTimeType.h"
#include <unordered_map>
```

I have checked that all of the include files exists and I have made another script to test if I can use them, and I can.

The reason why I don't stay with Ubuntu is because the Supercomputer I have to use is running centOS.

Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Please let my know if you need additional information.

Regards, 
Anders

#### Edit

With the GCC 4.8.5 version the program provided by NathanOliver compiles and run.
I compile it directly from terminal using:

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o main
./main
1 2 3 4 5
```

And it runs with `-std=c++0x`.
Somehow I cant use `-std=c++14`.
It gives the following error:

```
g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-std=c++14'
```

#### Edit

So to get back to the main problem. My Makefile I have, have the following line:

```
//Flags used by the compiler during all build types.
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:STRING=-std=c++0x
```

So I can't see why the program should not run?

Comment: Are you specifying the `--std=c++11` flag? Could be built to be the default on Ubuntu, not on CentOS.

Comment: Can you see if [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cfea54170eea753e) minimal ranged for example compiles?

Comment: The errors you get are pretty much identical to those I see with NathanOliver's example compiled with `--std=c++03`, but compiles with `--std=c++14`. Your problem is clearly this flag.

Comment: thank you for your answers I really appreciate it. You can see my reply in my question.

Comment: The problem is still not solved, can anyone help me? I am stuck at the text written after the second Edit in my question.